# Tensorflow.js: Resize image to specific byte size

Tags: image, tensorflow.js

For the prediction I need an image of the shape [null,7,7,256].

> const image = tf.reshape(tf.fromPixels(loadedImage).resizeBilinear([?,?]), [null, 7, 7, 256]);

But I don't know how to resize the image to be exactly 7*7*256 big.

> Error: Size(37632) must match the product of shape ,7,7,256

Edit: The code for the prediction is:

```
tf.loadModel(tf.io.browserFiles([uploadJSONInput.files[0], uploadWeightsInput.files[0]])).then(model => {
        console.log("model loaded");
        return model;

    }).then(pretrainedModel => {
        return loadImage2('http://localhost/myimg.jpeg', (src) => {
            const loadedImage = document.createElement("img");
            loadedImage.src = src;
            loadedImage.width = "275"
            loadedImage.height = "183"
            console.log("image loaded");

            const image = tf.fromPixels(loadedImage)

            resized = tf.image.resizeBilinear(image, [7, 7])
            const padded = resized.pad([[0, 0], [0, 0], [126, 127]])

            const pretrainedModelPrediction = pretrainedModel.predict(padded);
            const modelPrediction = model.predict(pretrainedModelPrediction);
            const prediction = modelPrediction.as1D().argMax().dataSync()[0];
            console.log(prediction);
        });

    })
```

Error:

> Error: Error when checking : expected flatten_Flatten1_input to have 4 dimension(s), but got array with shape [7,7,256]

Comment: What is the shape of the loaded image ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ResizeBilinear will resize the height and the width of the image, meaning that it does not affect the number of channel which is the last dimension of the shape of an image.

If your image has 256 as it last channel, then the following will work

```
tf.fromPixels(loadedImage).resizeBilinear([7,7])
```

Reshaping a tensor will only work if both sizes matches. 
const image = tf.ones([183, 275, 3 ])
resized = tf.image.resizeBilinear(image, [7, 7])
console.log(resized.pad([[0, 0], [0, 0], [126, 127]]).shape);

An image  is generally of shape [h, w, 3].

```
resize = tf.fromPixels(loadedImage).resizeBilinear([7,7]) // [7, 7, 3]
```

And then use `tf.pad` for the last dimension

```
const image = tf.ones([183, 275, 3 ])
resized = tf.image.resizeBilinear(image, [7, 7])
console.log(resized.pad([[0, 0], [0, 0], [126, 127]]).shape);// [7,7,256]

// reshape the tensor to be a 4d
resized.reshape([1,7,7,256])
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to pad 'resize' according to my original question? I always get 'TypeError: t.map is not a function' when I try to pad. I expect my paddings to be wrong, but I'm completly new to tensorflow.

Comment: I made a follow-up quenstion : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59244722/tensorflow-js-tf-pad-results-in-typeerror-t-map-is-not-a-function

Comment: Yes, I know. I was still trying on how to figure out which array to use for padding to get the expected tensor.

Comment: What is the shape of the loaded image ?

Comment: image.shape: Array(3) [ 183, 275, 3 ]

Comment: Thank you. But the first (or fourth) dimension is missing: 

Error: Error when checking : expected flatten_Flatten1_input to have 4 dimension(s), but got array with shape [7,7,256] ------- I will edit my original post to give more information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203974/discussion-between-edkeveked-and-de-facto).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it with a `Uint8Array`

```
const canvas: any = document.getElementById('canvas')
const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
const imageData: ImageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
const uint8array = new Uint8Array(imageData.data.buffer)
const rgbaTens3d = tf.tensor3d(uint8array, [canvas.height, canvas.width, 4])
const rgbTens3d= tf.slice3d(rgbaTens3d, [0, 0, 0], [-1, -1, 3]) // strip alpha channel
const smallImg = tf.image.resizeBilinear(rgbTens3d, [192, 192]); // 192,192 is dictated by my model
```