# Tensorflow.js: tf.pad results in TypeError: t.map is not a function

Tags: tensorflow, debugging, tensorflow.js

This code is from the TF API docs:

```
let t = tf.tensor([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
let padding = tf.tensor([[1, 1,], [2, 2]])
```

When I execute it:

```
tf.pad(t, padding, "CONSTANT")
```

I get:

> TypeError: t.map is not a function

I'm using the latest version of tfjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

padding is a normal js array of tuples ( array of arrray) and not a tensor.

As for now, the version 1.3.1, only the CONSTANT mode is supported. Here is the way to go:

```
let t = tf.tensor([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
let padding = [[2, 2,], [1, 1]]

tf.pad(t, padding).print()
//  [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
//   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
//   [0, 1, 2, 3, 0],
//   [0, 4, 5, 6, 0],
//   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
//   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```